# Date as longvalue to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-conversion

How to convert a long value like `2018051822111234L` to `yyyyMMdd HH:mm`?

```
2018051822111234 -> 2018 05 18 22:11:12.
```

I tried with `LocalDate.parse` and `DateFormatter(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ)`. It doesn’t work for me.

Comment: your long value should be a string

Comment: Convert to a `String`, then use `LocalDate.parse`

Comment: captial `Z` signals a timezone offset, which you doN#t have in your value. also the formatter has to match the value and not the desired output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to LocalDateTime raises an DateTimeParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522402/string-to-localdatetime-raises-an-datetimeparseexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String asString = Long.toString(2018051822111234L);
asString = asString.substring(0, asString.length() - 2);
String result = LocalDateTime.parse(asString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: So if i try to add the ms with the Pattern yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS and doesnt change the string length (String is ha a length of 17) it throws "cant parse at Index 0"

Comment: This is an Bug and will fix in Java 9 -> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085

Comment: The bug report you link to, @DevJam, mentions the following workaround: `DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3).toFormatter()`. I would prefer to try something similar to parse the full precision of your `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Monsieur Nizet has already provided [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48520315/5772882). It’s just me: I’d like to parse the full precision of the input `long`. It’s easier to throw away information later than it is to add it later if it wasn’t parsed at first.

Java 9 solution:

```
    DateTimeFormatter longFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmssSS");
    DateTimeFormatter desiredFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu MM dd HH:mm:ss");
    String asString = Long.toString(2018051822111234L);
    String result = LocalDateTime.parse(asString, longFormatter)
            .format(desiredFormatter);
```

This prints

```
2018 05 18 22:11:12
```

As you have already said yourself, this doesn’t work in Java 8 because of [this bug in the JRE: DateTimeFormatter won't parse dates with custom format "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085). The bug report mentions the following workaround:

```
    DateTimeFormatter longFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss")
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .toFormatter();
    asString += '0';
```

The workaround formatter has three decimals on the seconds, corresponding to milliseconds, whereas your `long` has only two. So above I am appending an extra `0` to the string before parsing. It was what I could get to work in Java 8 (also tried `appendFraction()`, in vain). Now the result is the same as above.