# String to LocalDateTime raises an DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-parsing, java.time.instant

I'm facing some trouble trying to convert `String` timestamp to `LocalDateTime`

I receive this string from database `2018013014364112` and it contains date and time which should be `2018-01-30 14:36:41.12` written in more readable format.

When I try to parse it to `LocalDateTime` i get an `Exception`

```
String timestamp = "2018013014364112"
LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS"))
```

Exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018013014364112' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

However, if i put space in anywhere in the `String` and `FormatPattern`, then I get the expected results

```
String timestamp = "2018 013014364112"
assert LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMddHHmmssSS")).toString() == '2018-01-30T14:36:41.120'
```

Also when i drop the "`SS`" from the pattern, I get expected results even without the space in the `String`

```
String timestamp = "20180130143641"
assert LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")).toString()
        == '2018-01-30T14:36:41'
```